# Can 'de' be used to express the manner or way in which an action is done?

Tags: sens, prépositions, de, à

Recently, I saw this example.

> Marc poussait le ballon **du** pied.

What's the difference between that sentence and this one?

> Marc poussait le ballon **avec** son pied

Is *de* then typically used in this manner or is it only employed in certain verb constructions? Additionally, is there any name/grammatical term for this usage of *de*?

Also, on a side note, would the above sentence be translated differently if I used *à* instead?

> Marc poussait le ballon à pied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ In the particular example chosen, the relation is not "manner" (in other words, "way"), but instead "means". You can replace "de" by "by means of" (the meaning of "de").
This is a construction that is used with mobile body parts and nouns that denote the movement  thereof, but it is not always possible to combine a verb that way; the forms have to be learned one by one, although certain patterns will progressively become apparent. Below, are listed some of them using typical verbs or verbal expressions.

*Body parts*

- faire signe des yeux, faire un signe de la main, faire un signe de la tête
- pousser de la main, pousser du doigt, pousser du coude, pousser du pied
- repousser de la main, repousser du pied
- toucher du coude, toucher du genou,

*Movements*

- faire signe d'un geste,
- pousser d'un mouvement,
- écarter d'un revers de  main
- rejeter/repousser/secouer d'une chiquenaude

2/ "De" is a preposition.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)) b) [Le compl. désigne une partie du corps]
> − Verbe + **de**
> *Verbes d'action.* Travailler de ses mains.
> ■ Une grande vilaine bête, lourde à soulever des genoux (Hamp, Marée,1908, p. 25).
> ■ Du pouce et de l'index [il] éjecta le mégot à distance appréciable (Queneau, Pierrot,1942, p. 8).Il m'a regardé de ses yeux clairs (Camus, Étranger,1942, p. 1126)
> ■  Dans sa hâte, elle s'était embarrassée, elle tâtonna, de la main gauche, pour saisir la rampe, qui trembla un peu. Daniel-Rops, Mort, où est ta victoire?1934, p. 2.

3/  <s>Marc poussait le ballon à pied.</s>

The use of "à" is not correct. The use of "à" in this sentence makes  it a meaningless one.

Comment: mobile body parts? Really?

Comment: @Lambie Yes, eyes, fingers, hands, feet, elbows, can be moved, and therefore can be called mobile.

Comment: No, we say that you can move fingers, hands, feet and elbows. We simply do not call body parts "mobile". However, a person who has difficulty walking has "limited mobility". And those who walk without difficulty are fully mobile.

Comment: @Lambie You are distorting grossly what is fact; I didn't say that body parts are mobile. Fingers _are_ mobile body parts : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fingers%20are%20mobile%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en //  SOED: capable of movement ; movable.

Comment: A finger may be mobile in medicine, but we don't say: mobile body **parts**.

Comment: Would this construction be similar to something like: "_a wave of the hand_" and others or would this have some sort of subtle difference. If it is similar I kind of feel like an idiot now by not realizing this early on.

Comment: @Xavier Exactly, the basic expressions "signe des yeux", "revers de la main", and others such as "claquement des doigts", are constructed on the basis of the same relation imbodied in "de" (object-subject — the hand does the waving).

Comment: Finally I get it! Now it's matter of hunting these verbs. Thank you.